# How to Unit test Service & controller (kotlin) in a Cordapp?

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, kotlin, controller, corda

I have gone through many documentations for getting a sample of unit testing service and controller in a Cordapp, not the flows (that is already done using in corda docs). Can anyone please help me to get an example cordapp which implemented service unit testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Mockito module for mocking and stabbing that is required for unit testing service functions and APIs.

[This link will direct more on how to mock CordaRPCops using mockito as an example.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63371734/can-we-mock-cordarpcops-in-cordapp-for-testing-purpose)

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look at the CordaService Autopayroll sample on github.

link: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/tree/master/Features/cordaservice-autopayroll

There's an ability to access registered services that gets used here in the testing code

```
//Test #1 check if the requestState is being sent to the bank operator behind the scene.
@Test
fun `dummy test`() {
    val future = a.startFlow(RequestFlowInitiator("500", b.info.legalIdentities.first()))
    network.runNetwork()
    val ptx = future.get()
    println("Signed transaction hash: ${ptx.id}")
    listOf(a, bank).map {
        it.services.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(ptx.id)
    }.forEach {
        val txHash = (it as SignedTransaction).id
        println("$txHash == ${ptx.id}")
        assertEquals(ptx.id, txHash)
    }
}
```

link: https://github.com/corda/samples-kotlin/blob/master/Features/cordaService-autopayroll/workflows-kotlin/src/test/kotlin/net/corda/examples/autopayroll/FlowTests.kt

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @davidawad. But I also need to mock the proxy too. Because I need to test from the api service file also. Can you pls share any projects which mocks proxy?