# Can we mock "CordaRPCops" in Cordapp for testing purpose?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, testing, mocking, corda

Is it possible to mock CordaRPCops so as to execute a flow in project without creating a standalone node or in-memory  node (like in a mock network) ? Kindly let me know.

[I am also adding a link which I found informative regarding this from github issues QA](https://github.com/corda/corda/issues/5461)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no specific class available mock `CordaRPCops` in the `TestDSL`. If you referring to mock some of the fuctionality of the node for cordapp testing, you should use the MockNode.

If you want to Mock `CordaRPCops` in the client app, you could use mockito to do so, example below:

**Test:**

```
@Test
public void testGetStateList(){
    CordaRPCOps cordaRPCOps = Mockito.mock(CordaRPCOps.class);
    Service service = new Service(cordaRPCOps);
    Vault.Page<MyState> myStatePage =
            new Vault.Page<>(Collections.EMPTY_LIST, Collections.EMPTY_LIST, 0L, Vault.StateStatus.ALL, Collections.EMPTY_LIST);
    Mockito.when(cordaRPCOps.vaultQuery(MyState.class)).thenReturn(myStatePage);
    service.getStateList();
}
```

**Service:**

```
public class Service {
    CordaRPCOps cordaRPCOps;

    public Service(CordaRPCOps cordaRPCOps) {
        this.cordaRPCOps = cordaRPCOps;
    }

    public List<StateAndRef<MyState>> getStateList() {
        return cordaRPCOps.vaultQuery(MyState.class).getStates();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashutosh. Can you pls share any github Cordapps which implemented this?

Comment: Ahh... I just wrote the code snippet for demonstration, let me check if there are any public repo that has a client test class.